# YouTube Data API v3 Quotas

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When trying to upload a YouTube video on our website an error pops up about exceeding our quota. Went on google cloud to see what our quota was and how much we are using. Found our quotas but there is no data showing how much we are using.

Is there a way to trouble shoot and figure out how much we are using to see if we are exceeding our quota?

Answer (score 0):

Go to google cloud console for your project.  Under library search for YouTube data api.  Then click manage and quotas, to see how much quota you have

You can check the metric page to see an estimate of your quota used.

[image]

> Is there a way to trouble shoot and figure out how much we are using to see if we are exceeding our quota?

Once you know what your current quota is, its probably only 10k unless you have requested an extension.   you need to check
**Queries per day** which is actually quote points per day for YouTube

Then you can check the [YouTube Data API (v3) - Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)

This page will show you the quota cost for each request.

Video.insert for example costs 1600 quota points, which will very quickly eat though the development quota.

[image]

If you are running out of quota the simplest thing to do is to request additional quota [YouTube Data API - Quota and Compliance Audits](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/quota_and_compliance_audits)

## If your Quota named: *Queries per day is 0*

From issue tracker [#208842985](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208842985)

> Hi. If you're seeing Queries per day quota set to 0 and the API is indeed enabled, then this means that your project’s access to YouTube Data API Service has been disabled.
> You should’ve received a notice via email regarding this action, which also contains the steps that need to be taken to regain the project’s access. But just in case you missed it, please fill out and submit the exceptions form below:
> [YouTube API Services - Audit and Quota Extension Form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en)

Comment: I have looked their and there is no data showing how much we are using. How do I get the data to show up.

Comment: you probably won't its not intended to be accurate. what is your current quote allotment?

Comment: 1,800,00 per minute and 180,000 per minute per user.

Comment: What is Queries per day?

Comment: Queries per day is 0

Comment: See my edit, your projects access to the YouTube Data API has been disabled.